# Cocoapods with Storyboard Scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, cocoapods

I am working in two apps, in which one of the ViewController does the same purpose in two apps(Like Help/about page). These two projects uses storyboard and uses two view controllers. Now, I am planning to integrate Cocoapods for my projects, so that I can reuse the same class/ViewController. My question is "Is there a way to  reuse this ViewController in two or more different projects using Cocoapods without breaking/modifying a storyboard ?" If yes, how to do that? If not possible, how can I reuse the same view with two different apps?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I had the same issue a few weeks ago.

RBStoryboardLink was the solution:
https://github.com/rob-brown/RBStoryboardLink

This library lets you connect Storyboards and works fine with projects from cocoapod.